# Schedule asp.net page on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, automation

what is the best way to schedule an asp.net page to run at a set interval on your server without using a third party cron service? is there a way to do this with an IIS addin or script with windows task scheduler

Comment: Run a page? I suppose you could have the server use a WebClient to request a page from itself...

Comment: I want to call a page every day which will run some automation code rather than build a console app or service running on the server

Comment: Can't you move the functionality out of the page and then have the application process call it on a schedule?

Comment: of course could run in a service or something but as a small script wondered if I could just put it on a page on a schedule to save building a service for a small script

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

Comment: I just find the idea of automatically accessing a web page to complete some task to be a bit Rube Goldbergian. Why have a web page life cycle as part of your task automation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Task Scheduler + wget for windows.

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would think about putting that logic(the code in the asp.net page) in a windows service (which we write) which has a timer.

Comment: wanted to try and avoid the windows service approach if possible

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any scheduling abilities in IIS, but you could enable/disable the service using scheduled tasks.  Not sure if you would consider that 3rd party or not....

Comment: I have used cron job services before but woundered if anyone knew of a way you can do it on your own server via windows, seems like not the case from the answers so far